# How to do hash arithmetic

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to subtract the ackedOns time from the startOn time in the hash to get how many epoch seconds it took to acknowledge the alert.

Here is the code:

```
url = "https://xyz"
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(req)
jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.body)
#troubelshooting step to see how many total alerts there are
total = jsonResponse['data']['total']
pp total

# create the collected_alerts hash
collected_alerts = { 'hosts'=> [],'dataPoints' => [], 'startOns' => [], 'ackedOns' => [], 'timeToAcks' => []  }

# iterate through the json
jsonResponse['data']['alerts'].each do |alerts|
   # store the interested json values into the appropriate hash
   collected_alerts['hosts'] << alerts['host']
   collected_alerts['dataPoints'] << alerts['dataPoint']
   collected_alerts['startOns'] << alerts['startOn']
   collected_alerts['ackedOns'] << alerts['ackedOn']

   # Calculate mins it took to acknowledge alert and store it in timeToAcks
   # Formula is Ack time - Start time which would give us seconds / 60 to give mins.             
   alerts['timeToAcks'] = alerts['ackedOn'].zip(alerts['startOn']).map{|a,s| a-s/60}    
end
pp collected_alerts

CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") {|csv| collected_alerts.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem} }
```

Here is the json response that i am trying to parse

```json
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": {
    "total": 3,
    "alerts": [
      {
        "dataPoint": "average",
        "ackedBy": "x",
        "dataSourceInstance": "Ping50Packets",
        "dataSource": "Ping50Packets",
        "host": "x",
        "endOn": 0,
        "ackedOn": 1392218853,
        "dataSourceInstanceId": 400554,
        "hostId": 1829,
        "type": "alert",
        "dataSourceId": 560,
        "ackedOnLocal": "2014-02-12 07:27:33 PST",
        "id": 6862895,
        "startOn": 1392197595,
        "thresholds": "> 200",
        "endOnLocal": "",
        "level": "warn",
        "ackComment": "Ack.",
        "value": "206.00",
        "hostDataSourceId": 137481,
        "acked": true,
        "hostGroups": [{
          "alertEnable": true,
          "createdOn": 1367604091,
          "id": 106,
          "parentId": 105,
          "description": "",
          "appliesTo": "",
          "name": "x",
          "fullPath": "x"
        }],
        "startOnLocal": "2014-02-12 01:33:15 PST"
      },
```

Comment: The specific error you are getting is hard to decipher for certain because you have not shown us the data structure of the `alerts` object. I'm guessing that it is a hash of single-value entries, and you wrote `alerts['startOns']` (plural) when you meant `alerts['startOn']` (singular). Or else you wrote `alerts['ackedOn']` (singular) when you meant `alerts['ackedOns']` (plural).

Comment: You still have not shown us what data is in `alerts`. Try `pp alerts` and then edit your post to put the output below your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data, you simply need to do:

```
collected_alerts['timeToAcks'] << (alerts['ackedOn'] - alerts['startOn'])/60
```

- Your origin code had a spelling mistake in one of the field names.
- You want to push these values into `collected_alerts`, not the current `alert`, right?

Alternatively, after your have looped through all the alerts:

```
ca = collected_alerts
ca['timeToAcks'] = ca['ackedOns'].zip(ca['startOns']).map{ |ack,st| (ack-st)/60 }
```

Further, instead of looping through the alerts one at a time and pulling out the pieces, I would do this:

```
alerts = jsonResponse['data']['alerts']
collected_alerts = {}
%w[host dataPoint startOn ackedOn].each do |field|
  collected_alerts[field] = alerts.map{ |alert| alert[field] }
end
```

Or even better:

```
alert_fields = %w[host dataPoint startOn ackedOn]
collected_alerts = Hash[ alert_fields.map{ |f| [f,alerts.map{|a| a[f] }] } ]
```

Explained, roughly in execution order.

- `alert_fields = %w[ … ]` — create a variable referencing an array of string values (space-delimited in the source code), i.e. `["ackedOn", "host", … ]`
- `alerts.map{ |a| … }` — Create a new array by taking each value in the `alerts` array, creating a variable named `a` that references that value, and use the result of the block as the value in the new array.

  - `a[f]` — for each alert in the `alerts` array, look up the key with the value of `f`. For example, when `f` is `"ackedOn"`, this looks up the value of `a["ackedOn"]`.
- `alert_fields.map{ |f| … }` — for each element in the array create a variable named `f` (for 'field') and run the contents of this block. Create a new array where the contents are, for each entry, whatever the final value of the block results in.

  - `[f, … ]` — after creating an array of all the values for a particular field in all the alerts, the result of this block is a two element array that is the name of the field followed by these values. For example, `[ "ackedOn", [1,3,16,4,44,7] ]`.
- `Hash[ … ]` — given an array of two-valued arrays, create a hash mapping the first value in each pair to the second value, i.e. `{ "ackedOn" => [1,3,16,4,44,7] }`

  - *This same `Hash[…]` method alternatively accepts an even number of arguments, pairing each even-numbered argument with the following one.*

With examples:

```
alert_fields = %w[ackedOn host dataPoint startOn]
#=> ["ackedOn", "host", "dataPoint", "startOn" ]

alerts.map{|a| a[f] }
#=> [5,3,4,5,1,6,8,2,…]

[f,alerts.map{|a| a[f] }]
#=> ["ackedOn",[5,3,4,5,1,6,8,2,…]]

alert_fields.map{ |f| [f,alerts.map{|a| a[f] }] }
#=> [
#=>   ["host",['foo','bar',…]], 
#=>   …
#=>   ["ackedOn",[5,3,4,5,1,6,8,2,…]]
#=> ]

Hash[ alert_fields.map{ |f| [f,alerts.map{|a| a[f] }] } ]
#=> {
#=>   "host" => ['foo','bar',…], 
#=>   …
#=>   "ackedOn" => [5,3,4,5,1,6,8,2,…]
#=> }
```

Comment: See my edit for ways to achieve the same goal with less typing.

Comment: Thank you the first part of your comment fixed my issue.

As for the 2nd part of the comment, i understand the first section.
I am trying to understand: 
alert_fields = %w[ackedOn host dataPoint startOn ackedOn]
collected_alerts = Hash[ alert_fields.map{ |f| [f,alerts.map{|a| a[f] }] } ]

first line is to create an array called alert_fields 
the thing i dont understand is where does the a and f come from in the second line.

Comment: @achan See my edit for explanation. And go read up about [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Hash.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Answer (score 1):

something like;

```
 alerts['tta'] = alerts['ackedOns'].zip(alerts['startOns']).map{|a,s| a-s/60}
```

Comment: I tried that syntax and get the following error:
     alerts.rb:61:in `block in <main>': undefined method `zip' for 1392240941:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Comment: Your first line indicates that alerts['ackedOns'] is an array, but your error shows that it is a number. You need to post more code.